# PHP Redirect breaks ajax so force one time Jquery page refresh

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

I'm using jquery mobile 1.4 to create a webapp. I have a form where the user uploads something to the database. After this upload they are redirected to another page where I thought the best thing to do would be to "disable" the back button by checking for a php session variable on the form and if that doesnt exist (they have pressed back after completing their task) the user gets re-directed back to the beginning of the form to prevent them from entering data into the database twice. The code I use for this is

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['RES_CUSTOMERID'])){
    header("Location: my_page_here.php",TRUE,301);
}
```

However, the `my_page_here.php` page uses ajax to load a table that the user can select from. After this redirect the table no longer loads and I have to refresh the page to get any data. I thought that a way round this would be to force a jquery refresh if the customer has come from this page. The way I have done this is:

```
window.onload = function() 
{         
    if (!window.location.search) 
    {   
        setTimeout("window.location+='?fromCustRes';", .10000000);
    } 
}
```

Which works however its a bit buggy when using android tab as you can see the flicker. I wanted to "fix" this by making it only refresh if the user has come from this specific page using `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];` and creating a hidden input value to pass this to the jquery and write it into my function but I cant get it to work. This is what I've been trying to do:

```
<input type='hidden' name='from' id='from' value=<?php echo $from;?> /> 

window.onload = function() 
{ 
    if ((($('#from').val()) === 'my string' )     
    if (!window.location.search) 
    { 
        setTimeout("window.location+='?fromCustRes';", .10000000);
    } 
}
```

Ive tried a few variations of this but I cant get anything to work, it just gives me a blank page like I'm breaking the ajax. If anyone has any solutions to this or any better ideas about getting the redirect to load the ajax without a page refresh it would be appreciated!

Comment: You just want a working redirect have you consider javascript for a redirect?

Comment: I used php as it needs to be based on whether session variables exist..?

Comment: I hope I understood your question? maybe this might help

   echo "<script> window.location.replace(\"index.php\")</script>";

Comment: lol that worked, I'm annoyed it was so easy! Thanks a lot, if you write it as an answer I'll accept and +1. Cheers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 echo "<script> window.location.replace(\"index.php\")</script>";
```